# How to remove the selected radio button and label one at time?

Tags: javascript

I am not able to remove the radio button and the label. I cannot figure out how the get the remove function to get the selected radio button and remove the button and the associate label.

```
function removeRadioItem() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("attr_radio");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radio = radios[i];
    if (radio.checked) {
      radio.parentNode.removeChild(radio);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj7L41cz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `addNewRadioItem` function, when adding the new radio box, you should cover that with `span` or `div` (so put radio button and label into one element and add that element.)

And on `removeRadioButton`, remove that element that covers the radio and label.

```js
function addNewRadioItem() {
  var htmlRadio = document.getElementById('radiopreview');
  var optionValue = document.getElementById('txtRadioValue');
  var optionDisplaytext = document.getElementById('txtRadioDisplayValue');

  if (optionValue.value == '') {
    alert('please enter option value');
    optionValue.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (optionDisplaytext.value == '') {
    alert('please enter option display text');
    optionDisplaytext.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var radiobox = document.createElement("input");
  radiobox.type = 'radio';
  radiobox.value = optionDisplaytext.value;
  radiobox.id = optionValue.value;
  radiobox.name = 'attr_radio';


  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = optionDisplaytext.value;

  var description = document.createTextNode(optionDisplaytext.value);
  label.appendChild(description);
  
  var radioDiv = document.createElement('span');
  radioDiv.appendChild(radiobox);
  radioDiv.appendChild(label);

  var container = document.getElementById('radiopreview');
  container.appendChild(radioDiv);

  alert("Option has been added successfully");
  optionValue.value = "";
  optionDisplaytext.value = "";

}

function removeRadioItem() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("attr_radio");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radio = radios[i];
    if (radio.checked) {
        var parentRadio = radio.parentNode;
      parentRadio.parentNode.removeChild(parentRadio);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="0" align="float-left" id="radioForm">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Preview</td>
    <td align="left">
      <div id="radiopreview"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Option Value</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="txtRadioValue" type="text" id="txtRadioValue" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Option Display Text</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="txtRadioDisplayValue" type="text" id="txtRadioDisplayValue" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="btnAddItem" type="button" id="btnAddRadioItem" value="Add Option" onClick="addNewRadioItem();" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="btnRemoveItem" type="button" id="btnRemoveRadioItem" value="Remove Option" onClick="removeRadioItem();" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answer is correct but I also have my own implementation

```js
function addNewRadioItem() {
  var htmlRadio = document.getElementById("radiopreview");
  var optionValue = document.getElementById("txtRadioValue");
  var optionDisplaytext = document.getElementById("txtRadioDisplayValue");

  if (optionValue.value === "") {
    alert("please enter option value");
    optionValue.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (optionDisplaytext.value === "") {
    alert("please enter option display text");
    optionDisplaytext.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var radiobox = document.createElement("input");
  radiobox.type = "radio";
  radiobox.value = optionDisplaytext.value;
  radiobox.id = optionValue.value;
  radiobox.name = "attr_radio";

  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.htmlFor = optionDisplaytext.value;

  var description = document.createTextNode(optionDisplaytext.value);
  label.appendChild(description);

  var container = document.getElementById("radiopreview");
  container.appendChild(radiobox);
  container.appendChild(label);

  alert("Option has been added successfully");
  optionValue.value = "";
  optionDisplaytext.value = "";
}

function removeRadioItem() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("attr_radio");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    let radio = radios[i];
    if (radio.checked) {
      let value = radio.value;
      radio.parentNode.removeChild(radio);
      let label = document.querySelector(`[for=${value}]`);
      label.parentNode.removeChild(label);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" align="float-left" id="radioForm">
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Preview</td>
        <td align="left">
          <div id="radiopreview"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Option Value</td>
        <td align="left">
          <input name="txtRadioValue" type="text" id="txtRadioValue" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Option Display Text</td>
        <td align="left">
          <input
            name="txtRadioDisplayValue"
            type="text"
            id="txtRadioDisplayValue"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left">
          <input
            name="btnAddItem"
            type="button"
            id="btnAddRadioItem"
            value="Add Option"
            onClick="addNewRadioItem();"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left">
          <input
            name="btnRemoveItem"
            type="button"
            id="btnRemoveRadioItem"
            value="Remove Option"
            onClick="removeRadioItem();"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of messy to stick and pluck straight into the DOM like that. Especially if you want to move into React (for example) at some point, you're going to want to stay away from direct DOM manipulation.

What I would recommend is you would have an array with all the added radios:

```
let radioArray = [];
```

Every time a `radio` is added, you push it to that array:

```
let newRadio; // Here you define JSX or straight element with label to go into newRadio
radioArray.push(newRadio);
```

This way you can read all radios from `radioArray`  in multiple ways; `map`, `for-loop`, etc.
You could also remove all radios easily by just clearing the array:

```
radioArray = [];
```

And by using `Array.indexOf()` for example you can even remove a specific radio from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the next sibling (label) first, and then remove the radio itself

```
if (radio.checked) {
  radio.nextSibling.remove()
  radio.remove()
}
```

**Runnable example**

```js
function addNewRadioItem() {
  var htmlRadio = document.getElementById('radiopreview');
  var optionValue = document.getElementById('txtRadioValue');
  var optionDisplaytext = document.getElementById('txtRadioDisplayValue');

  if (optionValue.value == '') {
    alert('please enter option value');
    optionValue.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (optionDisplaytext.value == '') {
    alert('please enter option display text');
    optionDisplaytext.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var radiobox = document.createElement("input");
  radiobox.type = 'radio';
  radiobox.value = optionDisplaytext.value;
  radiobox.id = optionValue.value;
  radiobox.name = 'attr_radio';


  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = optionDisplaytext.value;

  var description = document.createTextNode(optionDisplaytext.value);
  label.appendChild(description);

  var container = document.getElementById('radiopreview');
  container.appendChild(radiobox);
  container.appendChild(label);

  alert("Option has been added successfully");
  optionValue.value = "";
  optionDisplaytext.value = "";

}

function removeRadioItem() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("attr_radio");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radio = radios[i];
    if (radio.checked) {
        radio.nextSibling.remove()
      radio.remove()
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="0" align="float-left" id="radioForm">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Preview</td>
    <td align="left">
      <div id="radiopreview"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Option Value</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="txtRadioValue" type="text" id="txtRadioValue" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Option Display Text</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="txtRadioDisplayValue" type="text" id="txtRadioDisplayValue" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="btnAddItem" type="button" id="btnAddRadioItem" value="Add Option" onClick="addNewRadioItem();" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="btnRemoveItem" type="button" id="btnRemoveRadioItem" value="Remove Option" onClick="removeRadioItem();" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to be REAL sure that you want to remove nextSibling. I like your idea, but I'm always a bit held back on direct DOM manipulation.